# Why clientHeight or offsetHeight not available on ref element on toggled div in React component with useRef hook

Tags: css, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I have a React component which show and hide some content.

Here is [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/old-dust-j2ce8).

```
const Collapse = ({ children }: Props) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [height, setHeight] = useState<number | undefined>(0);
  const toggledHeight = isOpen ? height : 0;
  const myRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const toggle = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);

  useEffect(() => {
    setHeight(myRef.current?.clientHeight);
  }, [myRef]);

  // useLayoutEffect(() => {
  //   setHeight(myRef.current?.clientHeight);
  // }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div
        ref={myRef}
        className={`content ${isOpen ? "isOpen" : ""}`}
        style={{ height: `${toggledHeight}px` }}
      >
        {children}
        {console.log(height)}
        {console.log(myRef)}
      </div>
      <button type="button" onClick={toggle}>
        <span>Toggle content</span>
      </button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Collapse;
```

I want to create a css `height` transition when showing and hiding the content.

Why is `myRef.current?.offsetHeight` or `myRef.current?.clientHeight` not available and always `0`?

Answer (score -1):

In the Style you are passing the dynamic height. I think it's not getting in the pixels. So you need to change from

`style={{ height:` ${height+"px"} `}}`

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are telling it from the first moment to be 0 :)

No need to look for exact height number, just animate `max-height`

I've managed to animate you code like this:

```
const Collapse = ({ children }: Props) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const toggle = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div
        style={{
          maxHeight: isOpen ? '1000px' : '0px',
          transition: 'max-height 1s ease-in-out',
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </div>
      <button type="button" onClick={toggle}>
        <span>Toggle content</span>
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: I don't want to set maxHeight to a fixed value. I am really curious why `clientHeight` is not available on my toggled `ref` element...